How to display a list in a columnar fashion in Vue.js 3?
It might be best explained with an example (using Bootstrap grid).

1 item in list
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">item 1</div>
  </div>
</div>


2 items in list
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">item 1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">item 2</div>
  </div>
</div>


3 items in list
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">item 1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">item 2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">item 3</div>
  </div>
</div>


4+ items in list, same as 3 items in list except new rows are created

4 items / 3 = 2 rows are used
8 items / 3 = 3 rows are used


I'm sorry, but you're asking about CSS, and Vuejs3 is a JS framework. Are you perhaps talking about some other CSS framework you might be using along with your VueJs3? (ex: Vuetify)

The question has little to do with JavaScript. This is a problem that can be quickly overcome with a CSS crash course. The puzzlement arises from your insistence on the "row". Incorrect approach. The correct approach is to create a grid container, specifying that 1 row can contain a maximum of 3 items. If you insert, for example, 7 children into it, there will be 2 complete rows and 1 started row. Let me demonstrate.
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* 3 columns */
}

The width of 1fr means that each item should have the same width. The number 3 preceding it signifies the quantity of items in the repeat() function.
Example


function addItem() {
  const gridContainer = document.querySelector('.grid-container');
  const newItem = document.createElement('div');
  newItem.classList.add('grid-item');
  newItem.textContent = 'Item ' + (gridContainer.childElementCount + 1);
  gridContainer.appendChild(newItem);
}

function removeItem() {
  const gridContainer = document.querySelector('.grid-container');
  const lastItem = gridContainer.lastElementChild;
  if (lastItem) {
    gridContainer.removeChild(lastItem);
  }
}
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* 3 columns */
  gap: 10px; /* gap between grid items */
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
<button onclick="addItem()">+</button>
<button onclick="removeItem()">-</button>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 7</div>
</div>



Example # 2
Rereading your example, I see that you distinguish between whether there is 1, 2, or 3 elements in the given row. Accordingly, I provide several examples. In this second example, I demonstrate how you can detect with CSS that every "row", i.e., every 3n elements, contains one cactus, and how to set its column width.
/* If the last row consists of only one item, then that single item should span three columns. */
.grid-container > :nth-child(3n+1):last-child {
  background: red;
  grid-column: span 3;
}



function addItem() {
  const gridContainer = document.querySelector('.grid-container');
  const newItem = document.createElement('div');
  newItem.classList.add('grid-item');
  newItem.textContent = 'Item ' + (gridContainer.childElementCount + 1);
  gridContainer.appendChild(newItem);
}

function removeItem() {
  const gridContainer = document.querySelector('.grid-container');
  const lastItem = gridContainer.lastElementChild;
  if (lastItem) {
    gridContainer.removeChild(lastItem);
  }
}
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* 3 columns */
  gap: 10px; /* gap between grid items */
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* If the last row consists of only one item, then that single item should span three columns. */
.grid-container > :nth-child(3n+1):last-child {
  background: red;
  grid-column: span 3;
}
<button onclick="addItem()">+</button>
<button onclick="removeItem()">-</button>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 7</div>
</div>



Example # 3
Following example #2, I separately implemented what should happen when there are 2 columns left in the last row. Here it gets trickier, as following the previous example, the column width should be 1.5 for the last 2 items to make up the 3-column width. However, fractional values cannot be specified in grid. Therefore, I increased the total column width to 6. By default, each column is 2 wide, so a total of 3 columns fit. Thus, if there is only 1 item in the last row, it will be 6 columns wide. If there are 2 items in the last row, there is no need for a fractional value, as half of 6 is 3 columns.
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr); /* 6 columns */
}

.grid-item {
  grid-column: span 2; /* one item spans across 2 columns, leaving 3 items in one row */
}

/* If the last row consists of only one item, then that single item should span three columns. */
.grid-container > :nth-child(3n+1):last-child {
  background: red;
  grid-column: span 6;
}

/* If the last row consists of 2 items, they should fill the entire row equally. */
.grid-container > :nth-child(3n+2):nth-last-child(1),
.grid-container > :nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child(2) {
  background: green;
  grid-column: span 3; /* here we need half */
}



function addItem() {
  const gridContainer = document.querySelector('.grid-container');
  const newItem = document.createElement('div');
  newItem.classList.add('grid-item');
  newItem.textContent = 'Item ' + (gridContainer.childElementCount + 1);
  gridContainer.appendChild(newItem);
}

function removeItem() {
  const gridContainer = document.querySelector('.grid-container');
  const lastItem = gridContainer.lastElementChild;
  if (lastItem) {
    gridContainer.removeChild(lastItem);
  }
}
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr); /* 6 columns */
  gap: 10px; /* gap between grid items */
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: span 2; /* one item spans across 2 columns, thus, we create 3 columns out of 6. This is necessary to represent half, as span cannot be a fractional value */
}

/* If the last row consists of only one item, then that single item should span three columns. */
.grid-container > :nth-child(3n+1):last-child {
  background: red;
  grid-column: span 6;
}

/* If the last row consists of 2 items, they should fill the entire row equally. */
.grid-container > :nth-child(3n+2):nth-last-child(1),
.grid-container > :nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child(2) {
  background: green;
  grid-column: span 3; /* here we need half */
}
<button onclick="addItem()">+</button>
<button onclick="removeItem()">-</button>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 4</div>
</div>




Hint: The JavaScript addItem and removeItem functions, along with the two buttons calling them, have been included in the code only for the sake of more dynamic examples. Naturally, my solution is JavaScript-free and relies solely on CSS, making it quite efficient for anyone.
Since I only used CSS for my solution, there is no need to worry about changes to the array used for the list, and there is no need to run loops.
